# Color sequence game in Python

Tags: python

The code below is for color sequence guessing in python.

```
import random
import time

def colorgame():
    r='red'
    b='blue'
    g='green'
    y='yellow'
    v='violet'
    bl='black'
    o='orange'
    w='white'
    m='magenta'
    colors = [r, b, g, y, v, bl, o, w, m]
    sequence=[]
    win = True

    while win == True:


            else:
                win=False
```

In the first iteration say `sequence = 'red'` user enters `red` and it prints `"Correct"`. But, when it comes to the second iteration (say) `sequence = ['red', 'green']` and user enters `'red' 'green'` It is not returning correct. Please help me in correcting the code so that the user input is accepted as list and compared to the existing list (`sequence`)

Comment: Is that the actual indentation in your code? Because it doesn't make sense as it is here.

Comment: Please mention what is the problem that you are facing? or what is the error that is popping up.

Comment: You've fixed the indentation, but we are still none-the-wiser as to what the problem is. What is the user entering? Is it a space separated list of colours such as `black green blue yellow`?

Comment: The problem is he is checking a string against a list. An answer has been given already which fixes this

Comment: @N.J.Dawson: that's the main problem. The given answer does not necessarily fix the problem - it depends on what the user is expected to enter (it seems that they should enter the full sequence of colours seen thus far0. There are other problems too.

Comment: I tried using that along with `'black' 'green'` and `'black' and 'green'` but it still keeps adding to the sequence, and "Correct" isn't being printed

Comment: @mhawke to achieve what the original asker is wanting, this is one of the only problems limiting them. I'm in agreement that the question should definitely be formatted and worded better, but a new user won't know how to define their problem as much as they won't know how to fix it.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson: the OP could still accurately describe what the problem is and what the input is. Without that information any answer is just a guess.

Comment: @JianCalazan: what is the exact input that the user is expected to enter?

Comment: @mhawke inputting `red` without any quotes works for the first try (it prints "Correct"), after it has added another color it stops printing "Correct" whatever I input, quotes or no quotes

Comment: @JianCalazan: Really? I don't see how entering `red` would ever work because the code compares a list with a string which will never be equal. Have you posted the same code that you are testing with?

Comment: Yes as @mhawke mentioned entering `red` should not return "Correct" in first place. Also, are you (@JianCalazan) expecting the user to enter multiple colors at a time? or one color at a time? What will be your second user entry assuming `red` returns correct?

Comment: @mhawke It does, the same way that `s=['red']` and then inputting `'red' in s` would result in `True` I tried replacing the `== sequence` to `in sequence` but still the same result.

Comment: @PalepuKartheek the user is expected to enter how many colors the code produces, either with `' '` or with `and` in the middle, but neither of the two works after two or more colors have been produced.

Comment: Try this - `temp = [i for i in input().split()]; temp == sequence`

Comment: @PalepuKartheek sorry if this sounds dumb but where exactly am I to put it?

Comment: instead of `answer=input("Enter answer here: ")` replace it with `answer = [i for i in input("Enter answer here:").split()]` and then try executing. Note: It accepts the input with `' '` between the entry of colors.

Comment: @PalepuKartheek the code you mentioned fixed it. It's printing "Correct" now even with more than two colors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the comments and clear understanding of your problem I got something to answer:

```
answer = input("Enter answer here:").split()
```

**Edited**: Thanks for @mhawke

Comment: Why would `raw_input()` help? Judging by the `print()` function calls the OP is very likely using Python 3, in which case `input()` is the correct function to call.

Comment: `print()` works in 2.7 also right. Other than this and the indentation i was unable to find any significant problem in his code.

Comment: You may want to mention what you changed rather than just giving fixed code. I.E. why checking a string vs. a list won't ever match true

Comment: `['hello'] == 'hello'` returns `False`. Similarly its unclear of what the user enters in this case. Assuming he enters a color name I thought we should match it with a string. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The list comprehension serves no function here: `input("Enter answer here:").split()` is sufficient.